# How do I populate a hidden required field in django forms?

Tags: python, django, forms

I looked at other similar questions on Stackoverflow, but those situations do not apply to me.

I have a form with a `Queue` field that is a required field. This form is used in multiple places and in one such instance, I don't want the `Queue` field to be shown to the user. So, I simply did not render it on the template. But because this a required field, the form won't submit. How do I pre-populate this field while at the same time hiding it from the user?

I cannot make changes to the model or the form's save methods because this form is also used at other places.

forms.py

```
class PublicTicketForm(CustomFieldMixin, forms.Form):

    queue = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        label=_('Queue'),
        required=True,
        choices=()
    )
```

views.py:

```
def no_queue(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PublicTicketForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        form['queue'] = 9 # Tried to assign queue value to field, did not work

        if form.is_valid():
            if text_is_spam(form.cleaned_data['body'], request):
                # This submission is spam. Let's not save it.
                return render(request, template_name='helpdesk/public_spam.html')

            else:
                form.save()
    else:
        form = PublicTicketForm(initial={'queue': 9})  # tried this one too, did not work either
    return render(request, 'helpdesk/no_queue.html', {'form': form})
```

The `choices` for this form were populated in the views, but because I'm not rendering it in the template, I did not do it.

Comment: Why make it required at all?

Comment: Because the user in an other place should be able to choose what Queue he/she wants to put the form info into, only in this place do we hide it and make it go directly to Queue with ID 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do something like this in the template and that worked!

```
<input type="hidden" name="queue" value="9" />
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use formsets to be able to assign a specific value and show specific inputs to the user like [this](https://youtu.be/MRWFg30FmZQ?list=PL-51WBLyFTg2vW-_6XBoUpE7vpmoR3ztO)

Answer (score 2):

I just did this last night!

In forms.py declare the field with the HiddenInput widget (be sure to render it):

`scope = CharField(max_length=60,widget=HiddenInput())`

Then, in views.py you can apply the initial value:

`form = MyForm(initial={'scope': 'public'})`

Or using a CBV:

`initial = {'scope':'public'}`

Comment: I can't hide it in the form because that form is used else where as well, so I was able to do `<input type="hidden" name="queue" value="9" />` and that worked for me

Comment: Glad that it's working.  Something else I didn't think of earlier would be too subclass the Form and make changes there.  We have many options with Django.

Answer (score 1):

Don’t make a hidden field. Create another form class that doesn’t contain the field (subclassing will prevent repetition), then set the value in the view.

```
instance = form.save(commit=False)
instance.queue = 9
instance.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override POST data.

```
if request.method in ('POST', 'PUT'):
    data = request.POST.copy()
    data['queue'] = 9
    form = PublicTicketForm(data, request.FILES)
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to have a page which populate using GET args but not display the input fields (to prevent users to accidentally change the config of the objects), so I did this in my `admin.py`:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.forms import HiddenInput

from .models import SimpleNote

class SimpleNoteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("id",)

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, change=False, **kwargs):
        form = super(SimpleNoteAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, change, **kwargs)
        form.base_fields['content_type'].widget = HiddenInput()
        form.base_fields['object_id'].widget = HiddenInput()
        if "content_type" in request.GET and "object_id" in request.GET:  # simple note does not exist, so we must create it using GET parameters
            form.base_fields['object_id'].initial = request.GET['object_id']
            form.base_fields['content_type'].initial = request.GET['content_type']
        return form

admin.site.register(SimpleNote, SimpleNoteAdmin)
```